# Start service for every few seconds

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to start a service when wifi network connected.

If I start the service when wifi connected, by using

```
context.startService(intent_alarm);
```

it works fine.

I want to start the service for every 10 seconds after recieving broadcast. So I have used **AlarmManager**

Here is the code:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        public static AlarmManager am;
        public static PendingIntent sender;
      @Override
         public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
                 Intent intent_alarm = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent_alarm, 0);
                    am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    l += 3600L;
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,l, 3600L, sender);
                    //context.startService(intent_alarm);
    }
    }
```

I think here I gave 3.6 seconds as the intervel.

But the service not running, I checked it manually.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you properly declare your receiver in manifest file

Comment: yes. If I start it using startService, It works fine. I want to start the service for every 10 seconds.

Comment: <receiver
            android:name="com.example.broadcast_internetcheck.NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: This will drain the battery very quickly on the device.

Comment: @VigneshBala try greg code and let me know what is wrong

Comment: @NikPatel The broadcast receiver class works perfectly when I connected. I checked the service running when I just start it without AlarmManager

Comment: you have used PendingIntent.getBroadcast instread of  PendingIntent.getService

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the alarm manager to start **your** service:

```
Intent intent_alarm = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent_alarm, 0);
```

Comment: Nah it happens to all of us. If this solved please mark as answer to help others.

Comment: @GregEnnis i m using getService then its not starting my service but when i m using getBroadcast then its started the service

Answer (score 1):

you have used PendingIntent.getBroadcast instread of PendingIntent.getService
so use this - >

```
Intent intent_alarm = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent_alarm, 0);
```